# How do i get the code to re run an old path that was already taken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create an ATM that asks for a user name to log in and then for each user have three separate accounts to pick from. Within each of those accounts allow them to deposit, withdraw, and view balance. My problem is I am not very good with lists and I believe that is what is needed. I can not get the code to log in as a new user once I have already gone threw the code. example: I create a user Bob and log in and deposit money. Then I log out of Bob and want to create a new user Tim. when I create Tim it wont let me log it. It will keep giving me the same menu every time I put in Tim.

I believe I need to create a list of users, then a list for each user and I do not understand how to do so. Seeing from my code I just use set values for the funds in each account. Could this be a problem with why the main log in wont allow me to use another user?

```
user_list = []
data_list = []
index = -1

user_input = 0
user_account = 0
credit_input = 0
checking_input = 0
saving_input = 0

while user_input != 3:
    print("1: Login\n2: New User\n3: Exit")
    user_input = int(input("Please pick an option: "))

    if user_input == 1:
        username = input("Login: ")
        while username not in user_list:
            username = input("No user, try again: ")
        index = user_list.index(username)
        while user_account != 4:
            print("Accounts:\n\n1: Credit\n2: Checking\n3: Savings\n4:Exit ")
            user_account = int(input("Please pick an option: "))
            if user_account == 1:
                credit_funds = 0
                while credit_input != 4:
                    print("1: Deposit")
                    print("2: Withdraw")
                    print("3: Credit Account Balance")
                    print("4: Exit") 
                    credit_input = int(input("Pick an option: "))
                    if credit_input == 1:
                        number = int(input("Deposit amount: "))
                        credit_funds += number
                        print("Deposit of $", number)
                    elif credit_input == 2:
                        number = int(input("Withdraw amount: "))
                        while number > credit_funds:
                            print("\nInsufficient Funds")
                            break
                        else:
                            credit_funds -= number
                            print("\nSuccessful Withdraw of $", number)
                    elif credit_input == 3:
                        print("Avalable balance: $", credit_funds)


            elif user_account == 2:
                checking_funds = 0
                while checking_input != 4:
                    print("1: Deposit")
                    print("2: Withdraw")
                    print("3: Checking Account Balance")
                    print("4: Exit")
                    checking_input = int(input("Pick an option: "))
                    if checking_input == 1:
                        amount = int(input("Deposit amount: "))
                        checking_funds += amount
                        print("Deposit of $", amount)
                    elif checking_input == 2:
                        amount = int(input("Withdraw amount: "))
                        while amount > checking_funds:
                            print("\nInsufficient Funds")
                            break
                        else:
                            checking_funds -= amount
                            print("\nSuccessful Withdraw of $", amount)
                    elif checking_input == 3:
                        print("Avalable balance: $", checking_funds)


            elif user_account == 3:
                saving_funds = 0
                while saving_input != 4:
                    print("1: Deposit")
                    print("2: Withdraw")
                    print("3: Saving Account Balance")
                    print("4: Exit")
                    saving_input = int(input("Pick an option: "))
                    if saving_input == 1:
                        number3 = int(input("Deposit amount: "))
                        saving_funds += number3
                        print("Deposit of $", number3)
                    elif saving_input == 2:
                        number3 = int(input("Withdraw amount: "))
                        while number3 > saving_funds:
                            print("\nInsufficient Funds")
                            break
                        else:
                            saving_funds -= number3
                            print("\nSuccessful Withdraw of $", number3)
                    elif saving_input == 3:
                        print("Avalable balance: $", saving_funds)

    elif user_input == 2:
        username = input("Please pick a username: ")
        while username in user_list:
            username = input("Pick another please: ")
        user_list.append(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user 'logs out' (presses 4 when logged in) you set `user_account` to 4 (an exit condition). It is never unset after that. Therefore when another user tries to login, the program tests `user_account != 4`, fails that test, and never enters the while loop (`while user_account != 4`). I suspect the same will happen for all other exit conditions.

I suggest resetting the value of any inputs to 0 after taking the appropriate action. Alternatively, use `while True:` and explicitly `break` when an exit condition is reached.

For example:

```
while True:
    print("1: Login\n2: New User\n3: Exit")
    user_input = int(input("Please pick an option: "))

    if user_input == 1:
        print("Option 1 selected")
        # DO SOMETHING
    elif user_input == 2:
        print("Option 2 selected")
        # DO SOMETHING
    elif user_input == 3:
        break
```

Comment: So from the first list of options, the exit option is what i am using to end the code completely. It is my fault because after a log in i have option 4 as exit when it should say logout. After a user logs out i cant log back in. I tried adding a break at the end of both as you said and still no luck. Im sorry i know my code is hard to follow

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to fix the logic error caused by using `user_input` in the while loop condition

Answer (score 0):

```
users={};stop='r'
def login(name,users):
    if name in users.keys():
        return True
    return False
def create():
    name=input('please write your name')
    users[name]=0
def main(users):
    print('Welcome to my ATM\n')
    buff=input('SELECT one of the following:\nC)create account\nL)login')
    if(buff=='C' or buff=='c'):
        create()

    elif(buff=='L' or buff=='l'):
        name=input('name: ')
        buff2=login(name,users)
        if(buff2==False):
            print('your name is not in account list')

        elif(buff2==True):
            buff=input('SELECT:\nA)cash report\nD)delete account')   
            if(buff=='A' or buff=='a'):
                print(users[name])               
            elif(buff=='D' or buff=='d'):
                k=users.pop(name)
                print('finished! ')
while(stop=='r'):
    buff3=input("press 's' to stop ATM otherwise press enter to continue ...")
    if(buff3=='s'):
        break
    main(users)
```

I wish this works.